Is this proof of Riesz theorem for finite dimentional linear space rigorous?
I'm reading "Ballentine, Leslie E - Quantum mechanics: a modern development".

Corresponding to any linear vector space V there exists the dual space
of
linear functionals on V . A linear functional F assigns a scalar F (φ) to each vector φ, such that F (aφ + bψ) = aF (φ) + bF (ψ) for any
vectors φ and ψ, and any scalars a and b. The set of linear
functionals may itself be regarded as forming a linear space $V'$ if
we deﬁne the sum of two functionals as ($F_1$ + $F_2$)(φ) = $F_1$ (φ)+$F_2$ (φ).
Riesz theorem. There is a one-to-one correspondence between linear functionals F in $V'$ and vectors f in V , such that all linear
functionals have the form F (φ) = (f, φ) , (1.5) f being a ﬁxed
vector, and φ being an arbitrary vector.
For the present we shall only prove this theorem in a manner that
ignores the convergence questions that arise when dealing with
inﬁnite-dimensional spaces.
Proof. It is obvious that any given vector f in V deﬁnes a linear functional, using Eq. (1.5) as the deﬁnition. So we need only prove
that for an arbitrary linear functional F we can construct a unique
vector f that satisfies (1.5)....

"any given vector f in V deﬁnes a linear functional" - yes, but there is no guarantee that this functional will be in arbitrary $V'$. If functional F is defined as (1.5), then F'=F*2 is also a functional and such functionals make up another space. To me the proof is not complete in the book, but maybe I'm missing something? In wikipedia: Riesz_representation_theorem, the proof for Hilbert spaces includes additionally part for proving Riesz representation of F (vector f) is unique (and "Proof of norm formula").

What the book is claiming, is that we can define a map
$$P:V\to V'$$
by $(Pf)(\varphi) = (\varphi,f)$, now it's most likely aiming to prove this map is a bijection. This is in my opinion a bit redundant in the finite dimensional case. In that case what you can do is the following. Take any functional $T$, and
$$\psi=\alpha_1\varphi_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\varphi_n$$
Where the $\varphi_i$ form an orthonormal base (which always exists by Gram-Schmidt), therefore
\begin{align*}T\psi&=\sum_i\alpha_iT\varphi_i\\\\&=(\psi,f)\end{align*}
where
$$f_i=T\varphi_i$$
Where the equality is given because the $\varphi_i$ are orthonormal. Notice how the $f$ depends only on the choice of basis and on $T$, but not on the $\psi$. Lastly, the choice of $f$ is unique, because if $(\bullet,f)=(\bullet,g)$ as functional, then, by linearity $(\bullet,f-g)\equiv0$ and the only vector perpendicular to everything is $0$, and so $f=g$

I've just noted that the book defines dual space as: The set of linear functionals may itself be regarded as forming a linear space V', where as in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space:  consisting of ALL linear forms on V. So based on the book I imagined there are many distinct dual spaces for each vector space, whereas seems there is only one for each vector space. Do you agree the definition in wikipedia is more correct than the book's?
